# Approximating a function with a piecewise constant function

Tags: numerical-methods

I have some distribution X of values (which I don't know exactly but I can sample many times). I also have a function $f : X \to Y$ which may be complicated. I want to approximate $f$ with a piecewise constant function $g$, where the number of pieces is constant but I can choose the intervals, and where I minimize $|f - g|^2$.

Is this a studied problem? Are there some relatively simple ways of doing this in a good way?

Comment: Given the breakpoints in $g$, the value in a given interval should be just the average of all $f$ values in that interval.  It comes down to choosing the breakpoints.  I don't know any way better than a multidimensional minimizer, but maybe somebody does.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what your motivation is, or the nature of the function $f$, or how you hope to apply your desired piecewise function. etc.  Also, are you speaking, strictly, of a piecewise "constant" function (step function), or are you thinking about a piecewise "linear" function?

Comment: based on @Ross's answer, I'm assuming you mean strictly a piecewise constant function. I don't have any additional suggestions other than what Ross has offered.

Comment: Do you want to minimize the expected value of $|f-g|^2$? Or $\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)-g(x)|^2$, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I mean strictly a piecewise constant function. Let's say I want to minimize the expected value of |f-g|^2, although I would be happy with anything like that.

Comment: This is a studied problem: Konno, Hiroshi, and Takahito Kuno. "Best piecewise constant approximation of a function of single variable." Operations research letters 7.4 (1988): 205-210.